# discord py how to fetch messages with jump_url and reactions attributes

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a bot that would autoreact, check the amount of reactions on the messages in a channel, make a link to the message and send it on a moderation channel if it got 2 or more reactions, then log it's jump url in bot's directory. I cant find a way to fetch all the messages with jump_url and reactions attributes. im feeling super lost so i'll put the code here

```
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == 828579458167996420:
    channel = client.get_channel(828579458167996420)
    if message.attachments or "http" in message.content: 
      await message.add_reaction("<:MashaUpset:828589397074116709>")
      x = int
      messages = await channel.history(limit=21).flatten()
      f = open("message log.txt","r")
      readfile = f.read()
      f.close()
      if str(messages.jump_url) not in readfile:
        if messages.reactions[0].count >= 2:
          x = messages.reactions[0].count - 1
          link = messages.jump_url
          channel = client.get_channel(892065611876823100)
          await channel.send("this post was liked "+ str(x) + " times! "+ str(link))
          f = open("message log.txt", "a")
          f.write("\n" + str(messages.jump_url))
          f.close()
```

im a beginner, so sorry for the mess i've made

Edit: can't fetch `jump_url`, so instead fetching for `message.id`

Comment: During my tests, I wondered how this should even work. You can't handle all of this in an `on_message` event, since the counter will rise from time to time. Just to get the logic: Someone sends out a message, the bot adds a reaction, and then directly checks if the message has two or more reactions. After this event is over, the bot will never check the reactions again. Your `messages` part is also very messed-up, as you are trying to go over a `list` which does not work the way you want. Maybe explain your code a bit more, use `print` statements and handle it step by step.

Comment: At first, I made it so it would react and then wait 24 hours before checking the number of reactions the message got, then share jump_link to the message on a mod channel. After using the bot for a week thou, the bot would sometimes fail and not do anything (host service issue?). What I'm trying to do is have the bot check the reactions on the last 20 messages instead, making sure they were not already shared on mod channel by reading the `message log.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it. thx to Dominik for help

Changes I've done

- I've separated the script into 2 parts, an `on_message` and a `@tasks.loop`
- Added a `for x loop`
- Added an `await channel.fetch_message(x.id)` in the loop
- Fetched for `message.id` rather than `jump_url`
- Added if statement to check if the message has reactions

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.channel.id == 828579458167996420:
    
    if message.attachments or "http" in message.content: 
      await message.add_reaction("<:MashaUpset:828589397074116709>")

@tasks.loop(minutes=2)
async def check():
  channel = client.get_channel(828579458167996420)
  messages = await channel.history(limit=30).flatten()
  await asyncio.sleep(3)
  f = open("message log.txt","r")
  readfile = f.read()
  f.close()
  for message in messages:
    channel = client.get_channel(828579458167996420)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    if str(message.id) not in readfile:
      if message.reactions:
        if message.reactions[0].count >= 2:
         x = message.reactions[0].count - 1
         link = message.jump_url
         channel = client.get_channel(892065611876823100)
         await channel.send("this post was liked "+ str(x) + " times! "+ str(link))
         f = open("message log.txt", "a")
         f.write("\n" + str(message.id))
         f.close()
@check.before_loop
async def before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

check.start()
```

Comment: This looks way better. Is this version working for you?

Comment: yup, it's working perfectly! This is a lot more consistent than the old 1 whole def I used to have, even if their were multiple bot downtimes. thx again for pointing me at the right direction